# MSMessageTemplateLayout image not animating a '.gif'

Tags: objective-c, imessage-extension

I create a MSMessageTemplateLayout object and set the image property with gif image, the layout just shows a single image, and does not animate the gif.I tried following code,

```
    MSMessageTemplateLayout * layout=[[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc]init];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.gif"];
    layout.image=image;
    MSMessage * msg=[[MSMessage alloc]init];
    msg.layout=layout;
    [activeConversation insertMessage:msg completionHandler:^
    (NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
          NSLog(@"Error sending message %@", [error localizedDescription]);                
        }
    }];
```

It work for images but gif image loosing it's animation.I also tried with mediaFileURL but I get same problem.
Can anyone tell me any solution, how I sent gif image?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Animating iMessage app graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40536695/957768)