# Disallow users to download stickers from iMessage extension/app

Tags: swift, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I am creating an iMessage extension. When the user sends the sticker from my app in iMessage it(sticker) becomes available as an attachment(i button in iMessage conversation -> Images section). I do not want users to be able to download a sent sticker.

I have tried different ways to send a sticker: 
iMessage app using StickerView
Send a sticker with MSConversation.insert using MSMessages, MSStickers, Attachments. Only MSMessages don't allow the users to downloaded the sticker.

But I also need to be able to send a gif(it is not possible using MSMessages.MSMessagesTempletaLayout).

I have seen that the gifs without ability to download them work in Crossy Road iMessage extension so it is possible
Please give me some advise how can I do that?

Comment: This is not an answer to your current question (since i don't know how), but it is possible to send a gif using using the template layout, it's just not that straightforward. Check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536695/animated-imessage-app-graphics

Comment: can you try this by setting the stickerview property             cell.stickerview.startAnimating()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told since I’m using MSConversation I cannot use MSStickerView. While investigating the issue I have tried all possible ways to send this gif via MSConversation, but they didn’t work. The gif was sent but it was available to download.

The answer:
I was really shocked and disappointed when found the problem. 
All the time I was using simulator to test this. When I launched the app on my device - it worked! Have no idea why Apple made the stickers available to download in simulator. So actually the answer is - Test iMessage Apps only on a device.

P.S. It doesn’t look like a real answer but I hope it will be helpful for someone